# How does nested named tuple equality check work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

```
import typing
from enum import Enum


class Group(typing.NamedTuple):
    group_id: int
    group_name: str    


class Groups(Enum):
    A = Group(1, 'Group A')
    B = Group(2, 'Group B')


class Member(typing.NamedTuple):
    member_id: int
    member_name: str
    member_group: Group


class Members(Enum):
    member1 = Member(1, 'Merber 1', Groups.A.value)
    member2 = Member(2, 'Merber 2', Groups.B.value)

print(Groups.A.value)
print(Groups.B.value)

print(Members.member1.value)
print(Members.member2.value)

print(Groups.A.value == Groups.B.value) # simple named tuple
print(Members.member1.value == Members.member2.value)   #nested named tuple
```

Named tuple equality check for simple named tuple (that is - non nested) checks for value matching. Key is ignored.

How does named tuple equality check work for nested named tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) function creates a subtype of `tuple`. The docs don't mention anything about namedtuples having different equality checks to regular tuples, and the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb8ac57af26c4eb96a8230eba7492ce5ceef7886/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L304) shows that a namedtuple type does not override `__eq__`.

So, equality of namedtuples is tested in exactly the same way as equality of regular tuples: they must have the same values in the same order. "Same" is tested by equality of the values; since regular tuples don't have named attributes for their values, nor distinct type names, the `tuple.__eq__` method won't look at the attribute names or the type name.

Some demonstrations:

```py
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> A = namedtuple('A', 'x y')
>>> a = A(1, 2)
>>> a == (1, 2)
True # equal to a regular tuple
>>> B = namedtuple('B', 'z w')
>>> b = B(1, 2)
>>> a == b
True # equal to a different namedtuple type with different attribute names
>>> A([1, 2], [3, 4]) == B([1, 2], [3, 4])
True # equal when values are different by identity
>>> A(a, b)
A(x=A(x=1, y=2), y=B(z=1, w=2))
>>> B(b, a)
B(z=B(z=1, w=2), w=A(x=1, y=2))
>>> A(a, b) == B(b, a)
True # equal when values are equal namedtuples
```